# Delete Single Item in Firebase Database with Android Generated by Push()

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I haven't been able to find a clear answer that helped me delete a node that has been added as a POJO, and then given a key generated by push(). All I'm trying to do is delete a given item when it's being long pressed on a listview. I've tried removeValue() but all that does is delete the whole parent node as well, which isn't what I wanted. I don't know how to get the generated key.

Could you provide an example of getting a reference say /node/ so that I can use **.removeValue()** on that inside a listview. My issue is I'm trying to grab the proper pushed key in the list so that I can reference that key under /nodes and then delete that one singular item instead of the entire nodes reference which is what **mDatabase.child("nodes").removeValue()** does currently. When I want something like **mDatabase.child("nodes").child(pushedKey).removeValue()**.

when i send data to nodes it looks like this.

```
mDatabase.child("nodes").push().setValue(POJO);
```

I'm using this to delete it...

```
 main_ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //Delete node
            listAdapter.mNodes.remove(position);
            mDatabase.child("nodes").push().getRef().removeValue();
            listAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Removed Item at: " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            main_ListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**example**

[image]

Any help would be grateful thanks. :)

Comment: Did you try? firebase.child("nodes").removeValue();

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/remove.html

Comment: No longer accurate. Firebase.google.com/docs is most current.

Comment: If you notice that is what I'm doing. Mdatabase is a reference to that exact same location.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

To accomplish this with using nodes generated by **.push()**. You need to change your POJO(plain old java object) that represents your data. Just add a string field for **key**.

Then delete existing data or add the key field to all data in the node.

I used this code, and then calling the method when I added the new object to my database.

```
private void GenerateKey() {
    mKey = mNodeRef.push().getKey();
    Log.i(TAG, "NODE CHILD KEY: " + mKey);
    if(mKey.equalsIgnoreCase(mKey)){
        mKey = mNodeRef.push().getKey();
        Log.i(TAG, "NEW NODE CHILD KEY: " + mKey);
    }
}
```

Then in the area where I delete it, I use this code. Specifically I am deleting on long press, and then giving the user the choice to delete it or not.

```
main_ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            //Dialog
            final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Please Don't Kill Me!");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Kill Me...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Delete node
                    Log.d(TAG, "NUM of NODES: " + listAdapter.mNodes.size());
                    NodeObject pos = listAdapter.mNodes.get(position);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Generated Key: " + mKey);
                    String selectedKey = listAdapter.mNodes.get(position).getKey();
                    Log.i(TAG, "Selected Key: " + selectedKey);
                    mNodeRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
                    listAdapter.mNodes.remove(pos);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    main_ListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Node has been murdered terribly."
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).
                    setNegativeButton("Don't Kill Me!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fine, ya coward."
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

            dialogBuilder.create().show();
            /*
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item at: " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""  +listAdapter.mNodes.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/


            return true;
        }
    });
```

Lastly, I called the method where I add the node.

```
private void addNode() {
    //Get generated key set it to the node
    GenerateKey();
    Log.i(TAG, "ADD NODE GENERATED KEY: " + mKey);
.......
}
```